# Conditional probability find P(A)

Tags: probability

Find $ P(A) $ given:

$ P(A|B) = 0.7, P(A|B^c) = 0.3 $ and $P(B|A) = 0.6 $

I looked through my probability course materials and couldn't find any conditional probability properties / formulas that could be used here (I think).

Anyway im not looking for a straight up answer, maybe you could point me in the right direction eg showing property or formula that could be used here for solving this.

Thanks!

Comment: $P(A)=P(A \cap B)+P(A \cap B^c)$. Can you calculate these two?

Comment: The definition of $P(A \mid B)$ is $\dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write

$$
P(A)=P(A\mid B) P(B)+P(A\mid B^c)P(B^c)=0.3+0.4P(B)
$$

and

$$
P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(B\mid A)P(A)}{P(B)}\Rightarrow P(A)=\frac{7}{6} P(B)
$$

Thus $P(A)=\frac{7}{138}$

Comment: The second formula is the Bayes' theorem which I did consider but tought it was a dead end... By using your formulas I dont understand how you got $ P(B^c)$ I got this far: $ 280 P(A) = 210 P(B^c) $

Comment: $P(B^C)=1-P(B)$ substitute at the second part of the first equation.